# Starting another activity in Handler#postDelayed(Runnable, long) yields "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length"

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler

When I start an activity in `Handler#postDelayed(Runnable, long)` I get an error log message (yes, repeated twice):

```
03-19 18:39:26.628: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11502): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-19 18:39:26.628: E/SpannableStringBuilder(11502): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Application does not crash, however it is annoying to see this error all the time. I get no other output in the LogCat in this example.

My first activity:

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startActivityTwoDelayed();
    }

    private void startActivityTwoDelayed() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this,
                        ActivityTwo.class);
                startActivity(captureIntent);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

My second activity:

```
public class ActivityTwo extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test03"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityOne"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityTwo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println` in Android.  If you want log messages then use `Log.d("AppName", "Log Message");`.  This likely isn't causing your problem but it's just good practice/the proper way of sending log messages for the platform.

Comment: @MCeley, thanks for the comment. I am aware of that. `System.out.println` does not cause the problem in this case.

Comment: I was sure it wasn't your problem.  Just wanted to leave the tip.  Some people getting into Android come from a more traditional Java background where `System.out.println` is used so I just wanted to share the info in case you weren't aware of other logging solutions.  Also, could you post more of your logcat output that shows the full stack trace?

Comment: @MCeley, thanks for the note. I updated the question an made it clear what output I get.